# unable to open /opt/miniconda3

Tags: terminal, miniconda

I have a ChromeOS and I installed Miniconda3 on it. It is installed in the Linux folder under sub-folder /opt
When I try to enter the command "/opt" - it shows

- bash: /opt: Is a directory
  But when I try to command "/opt/miniconda3" - it shows
- bash: opt/miniconda3: No such file or directory

Can anyone explain why is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

Use `/opt/miniconda3`, you miss the leading slash and shell search for `opt/miniconda3` related to your current directory